# Bottom Sheet Drawer in Material design

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-navigationview

```
class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, container, false)
}
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        // Bottom Navigation Drawer menu item clicks
        when (menuItem!!.itemId) {
            R.id.nav1 -> context!!.toast("you clicked one")
            R.id.nav2 -> context!!.toast("you clicked two")
            R.id.nav3 -> context!!.toast("you clicked three")
        }
        true
    }


}

// This is an extension method for easy Toast call
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 600)
    toast.show()
}

}
```

What i want to achieve is after clicking navigation icon in bottom app bar a modal bottom sheet is created and and a navigation drawer is shown in it.In above code i kept three items in it.Up to here everything is okay but when comes to handling item clicking part then the line:

```
navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
```

shows error. It tells :

```
unresolved type:setNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

And `unresolved type in:menuItem`

Here is `fragment_bottomsheet.xml` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_drawer_menu"/>

</android.support.design.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is wrong in am doing here?

Comment: Add your fragment_bottomsheet.xml layout. To the question.

Comment: added in the question

Comment: yeah !! but navigation_view on item selected listener doesnt work why ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like issue comes from `Context.toast(message: CharSequence)` which you could use anko for that:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.6"
```

---

Anyways, you can check the output by:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

And you'll see that it will work.

**UPDATE:**

Try using this inside your `BottomNavigationDrawerFragment`:

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            // Bottom Navigation Drawer menu item clicks
            when (menuItem.itemId) {

                R.id.home ->{

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
//                R.id.nav1 -> context!!.toast(getString(R.string.nav1_clicked))
            }
            // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
            // For example, swap UI fragments here
            true
        }

        close_imageview.setOnClickListener {
            this.dismiss()
        }

        disableNavigationViewScrollbars(navigation_view)

    }
```

Comment: in Mainactivity or in above class?

Comment: Inside the MainActivity -> `onCreate()` method. Just set it as usual we set for the `Toolbar` and this time, for `BottomBar`.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Your codes looks fine but, `Context.toast` seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The below method is worked for me.

```
class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private val TAG: String = ImageChooserDialog::class.simpleName.toString()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_image_chooser, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation_view)
        .setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.action_camera -> Log.e(TAG, "action_camera")
                R.id.action_gallery -> Log.e(TAG, "action_gallery")
            }
            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener  true
        }
    }
}
```